# Swapping two movements (tuples) in a list

Tags: python, tuples, swap

I have a list of tuples where each tuple represents the movement from city x to city y, in this case [(x,y)]. Imagining that I will travel through city a, b, c and d in this order the list would look like this: [(a, b), (b , c), (c, d)] where the first position of the tuple represents the departure and the second the arrival.

I have to swap cities from the final route. Imagining that in the previous example, instead of being a, b, c and d it would be a, d, c and b and the final tuple would be [(a, d), (d , c), (c, b)]. Do you know any way to make this exchange ? It's just that I can't swap the whole tuples, because I'm swapping cities and not the trip. And I have to keep the arrivals and departures coherent.

Thanks.

Comment: What if you just create your final tuple after processing your list and swapping the elements?

Comment: I can't, the swap can only happen after a trip is calculated.

Comment: Tuples are immutable, You can create a new list of tuples from the given data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) are immutable, meaning you cannot change a tuple once it has been created. So you'll need to transform data first, order it the way you like, and then convert it back to tuples.

I suggest you use lists with single element to save route e.g. `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`. Swapping element in the list has O(1) complexity, and then you can iterate trough list and create a list of tuples again, something like

```py
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
res = []
for i in range(len(l) - 1):
    res.append((l[i], l[i+1]))
```

Comment: That's the approach I ended up taking and it seems to me to be the right one. I transformed the list of tuples into a single list without duplicates but keeping the order. Then I transformed the resulting list into a list of tuples as you exemplified.  Thanks for the answer.